# Bash: display current loop number in "for loop" command

Tags: bash

```
bulknomer=(`cat /tmp/bulknomer`)
bulkpesan=`cat /tmp/bulkpesan`
for i in "${bulknomer[@]}"; do
    echo  "send sms $i $bulkpesan"
done
```

`$bulknomer` has multiple values `(+6281 +6282 +6283 +6284)`. How do I display the number of current loop?, so for instance while it's still sending an sms to a number on the list, it shows something like this on the linux terminal:

```
1. Sending sms to +6281
2. Sending sms to +6282
3. Sending sms to +6283
4. Sending sms to +6284
```

Comment: Is your question how to include an incremented number in a bash for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iterating array from 1st element to last, you can do this:

```
len=${#bulknomer[@]}
for ((i=0; i < len; i++)); do
    j=$((i+1))
    echo  "($j of $len): send sms ${bulknomer[$i]} $bulkpesan"
done
```

`${#bulknomer[@]}` gives length of the array. And `for ((i=0; i < ${#bulknomer[@]}; i++))` is iterating array from position 0 to `length(array)-1`.
`j=$((i+1))` gets variable `j` from 1.

However for your case you don't really need to create an array. Better script will be:

```
#!/bin/bash

bulkpesan=$(</tmp/bulkpesan)
i=1
while read -r line; do
    echo  "$i. send sms $line $bulkpesan"
    ((i++))
done < /tmp/bulknomer
```

Comment: Can you please explain your code so that I won't have to ask the same question in the future?

Comment: one little question, how do I display this `(1 of 500)` so `500` is the total loop it'll occur?

Comment: so the result will show like this: `(1 of 500)....``(2 of 500)....``(3 of 500)....`

Comment: I implemented your updated code but it gives me this:
`(3 of 5): send sms 5(this is supposed to be the delivery number) mysmscontent`
How do I fix that?

Comment: oh sorry there was a typo, it is fixed now. Try again